# Rails 3 HABTM join table migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a HABTM association between `Users` and `Groups` in my Rails 3 app. The book I'm following to learn Rails recommends running the following command line to create the join migration:

```
rails generate migration create_groups_users
```

However in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) it looks like I should've run:

```
rails generate migration create_groups_users_join_table
```

So that the following would be in my `_create_groups_users.rb` migration:

```
class CreateGroupsUsersJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
```

Is adding `join_table` required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding join_table at the end is not explicitly required. Your first command 'create_groups_users' is fine. I've done this in rails 3.0.9 and it works.

You can double check by opening up the migration file and checking that it looks like:

```
create_table :groups_users, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :group_id
  t.integer :user_id
end
```

The :id => false is needed for a join table as it shouldn't have its own id field.

Comment: Great that's what I have. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The last argument in your call to `rails generate migration create_groups_users` just denotes the class name and a part of the file name of the migration. So it does help to find the migration you have created, the migration file itself is (inside the class body) empty. So both versions are ok.